# Error to deserialize hashtable in powershell

Tags: powershell

I create hashTable and serialize to xml. After that I want import from xml to hashtable. But I have error. Can you help me fix bug?

```
$ArrayVariables=@{}
$ArrayVariables.Add("serviceNameArray",$serviceNameArray)
$ArrayVariables | Export-Clixml "test.xml"
$arrayOfConfig=Import-Clixml "test.xml"
$arrayOfConfig.Get_Item("serviceNameArray")//error
```

Comment: 1) Please explain the error that you encounter.
2) Please explain what is $states, the variable where the error occurs is never mentioned anywhere else.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Should be this:

```
$ArrayVariables=@{}
$ArrayVariables.Add("serviceNameArray",@("myservice1","myservice2"))
$ArrayVariables | Export-Clixml "test.xml"
$arrayOfConfig=Import-Clixml "test.xml"
$arrayOfConfig.Get_Item("serviceNameArray"); #comment
```

1. $serviceNameArray is not defined in this scope.
2. $states is not defined.
3. Comments are denoted with # in Powershell.

Not such which one of these caused this issue, so I've listed all 3.

Comment: Ok.Thank you! I fixed my bug.